Remove default class function (like .ToString) from a class
As asked in the title, how do I remove default functions from class (like .ToString, .Equals, .GetHashCode, ...) ?
Bellow example of the class itself :
Public Class FontConstants

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Helvetica As String
        Get
            Return "Helvetica"
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property TimesRoman As String
        Get
            Return "Times-Roman"
        End Get
    End Property

End Class

Find in the attached screenshot the function that I would like to not see.
Would this be possible ?
Thank you & kind regards,
FINET L.
I've spend an hours trying to find the answer on Internet but with no luck.

You might be able to hide it from Intellisense by overriding and applying EditorBrowsableAttribute to the overrides... but you could definitely end up still calling those methods. Perhaps you should have a Module instead of a class?

I don't know why, but both approaches don't work in VB.NET. The methods from System.Object are still visible in intellisense. @OP: You should use a Module or Shared class anyway, since your class is just used for constant like properties. Btw, i would really use constants: Public Const Helvetica As String = "Helvetica"

... and you should NOT use your properties on an instance of this class(which is impossible if it's shared). So dont use: New FontConstants().Helvetica  but FontConstants.Helvetica. Then you also don't see the inherited members.

Every type in .NET inherits ToString() from System.Object. You cannot change that. Use Jon's and Tim's advice.
